# Enable xsd validation using CXF

Tags: cxf, jax-ws, xsd-validation

Please,how can i enable xsd validation inside server using cxf.
You find below my code used to publish web services:

```
JaxWsServerFactoryBean Factory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
Factory .setServiceClass(Class.forName(serviceName);
Factory .setAddress("/jaxws" + url);
Factory .create();
```

So,where i can add xsd validation?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

`java.util.Map<String, Object> props = new java.util.HashMap<>();
props.put("schema-validation-enabled", "true");
Factory.setProperties(props);`

See: http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIturnonschemavalidationforjaxwsendpoint?